# Laravel DomPDF, load_font unexpected index

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I am using [Berryvdh/Laravel-dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf)

in fresh installation `vendor/dompdf/dompdf/lib/php-font-lib` is empty, so I resort to install it with composer `phenx/php-font-lib (0.2.2)` and copy the library over to the project and run with

```
 `php load_font.php 'LiHei' \LiHei.ttf`,
```

the script created a `dompdf_font_family_cache.php` instead of `dompdf_font_family_cache.dist.php` that I need so I mod it and add it

```
'lihei' => array(
'normal' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'LiHei',
'bold' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'LiHei',
'italic' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'LiHei',
'bold_italic' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'LiHei',
```

to the array but than I got this error

> Undefined index: C at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Undefined index: C', ... in class.pdf.php line 2260

in class.pdf.php line 2260

```
foreach ($font['C'] as $num => $d) {
    if (intval($num) > 0 || $num == '0') {
        if (!$font['isUnicode']) {
            // With Unicode, widths array isn't used
            if ($lastChar>0 && $num>$lastChar+1) {
                for ($i = $lastChar+1; $i<$num; $i++) {
                    $widths[] = 0;
                }
            }
       }
       $widths[] = $d;
       if ($font['isUnicode']) {
           $cid_widths[$num] = $d;
       }
       if ($firstChar == -1) {
          $firstChar = $num;
       }
       $lastChar = $num;
    }
}
```

lihei.ufm which contain the following

```
StartFontMetrics 4.1
Notice Converted by PHP-font-lib
Comment https://github.com/PhenX/php-font-lib
EncodingScheme FontSpecific
Copyright ⡣⤠䍯灹物杨琠䑹湡䍯海慲攠䍯牰⸠㈰〳
FontName 쓗뛂⁐牯
FontSubfamily Media
UniqueID 䱩䡥椠偲漻‶⸰搴攲㬠㈰ㄴⴱㄭ㈶
FullName 쓗뛂⁐牯
Version 㘮つ㑥
PostScriptName 䱩䡥楐牯
Trademark 呲慤敭慲欠批⁄祮慃潭睡牥⁃潲瀮
Weight Medium
ItalicAngle 0
IsFixedPitch false
UnderlineThickness 50
UnderlinePosition -110
FontHeightOffset 0
Ascender 860
Descender -140
FontBBox -60 -171 1003 860
EndFontMetrics
```

when I check ufm that come with default it contain a matrix of data one of them is [C].

Answer (score 0):

so, I just keep trying different font until I hit one that is able to create a readable ufm.  just for future reference the font I ended up using is Microsoft YaHei.

Comment: does Microsoft YaHei supports Korean?